# ldd: not an ELF file, but the file is an ELF file

Tags: linux

When I execute

```
ldd cat
```

the result is

```
cat: not an ELF file.
```

But I am sure that this file is intact.

```
$ file cat
cat: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /some/interpreter, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=d35b1b0d6770131a41609614572853866beb7f6e, not stripped
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What does output: `type ldd`? `which ldd`? `whereis ldd`? `/bin/ldd cat`? `\ldd cat`? What directory are you in? What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: And most important : Is this related with programming?

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to Linux. I have used a cross-compilation environment before and I specified the environment variable `$PATH`, which caused the system to use the ldd in the corresponding directory.